# tycho shots a warning when my entry is longer than 100 chars

Tags: eclipse-rcp, tycho

after update to tycho 0.14.0, i'm seeing this warning:

```
[WARNING] Entry: germantechEcfNfe/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal_3.2.500.v20110510/themes/slate/graphics/standby/fs_standbyhov.gif longer than 100 characters.
```

any way to disable this kind of verification?
thank you guys

**edit**: my build isn't broke or something, but my log is getting full and becomes hard to read the output

Comment: how did the @jsievers answer resolve your issue?

Comment: from his link: `Sets the TarArchiver behavior on file paths with more than 100 characters length. Valid values are: "warn" (default), "fail", "truncate", "gnu", or "omit".`

Comment: of course the linked documentation for the maven assembly plugin is correct, but I just wanted to know if that setting actually solved your original problem regarding tycho builds, did it?

Comment: yep :) actually, worked, but I'm not generating tar.gz files for a while

Comment: I kindly ask you to review my answer, and possibly consider the opportunity to change your accepted answer because your actual choice may be misleading to other users

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before the 0.14 release there was no way to build product archive files using the .tar.gz format, this is probably the reason you didn't get any error from previous builds.

I have the same problem and by looking at the `tycho-p2-director-plugin` [sources](http://git.eclipse.org/c/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho.git/) I discovered that it uses the plexus archiver directly instead of delegating to the `maven-assembly-plugin`.

So by setting the `tarLongFileMode` property in the `maven-assembly-plugin` configuration won't remove warnings from your build log.

Answer (score 5):

the warnings are caused by the maven tar archiver. By default, it warns for tar entries with path length > 100 chars. Considering this is an ancient tar format limitation, I changed the default to "gnu" for tycho 0.17.0-SNAPSHOT so you should no longer get these warnings:

https://github.com/eclipse/tycho/commit/5db5cc2b76bdba8526cfc4acb66b3e4674f23f03